# PHP Operator "foo ?? bar", is this equivalent to "foo ? foo : bar"?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have just had a wordpress template fail giving E_PARSE errors on a number of lines with the following syntax:

```
$thumbnail_size = $post->image_size ?? 'medium';
```

I am not familiar with the ?? operator so replaced the lines with this:

```
$thumbnail_size = $post->image_size ? $post->image_size : 'medium';
```

1. Is this an equivalent statement?
2. Is there any reason why ?? should fail? (PHP Version 5.6.40, Wordpress 6.1.1)

The original code was working 3 days ago.  Wordpress version hasn't changed and PHP Info doesn't suggest the PHP version has changed for over 6 months.

Comment: "PHP Version 5.6.40" — Yikes! [5.6 has been out of support for over 4 years!](https://www.php.net/eol.php). Upgrade ASAP.

Comment: `?:` checks for falsyness, `??` for nullness

Comment: `??` was added in PHP 7 (which went out of support at the same time as 5.6).

Comment: Not sure who fixed the PHP version at that but looks like I can update it to at least 7.2.34 and revert my changes.  Not my site/server so I hadn't checked previously.

Answer (score -1):

The [null coalescing operator `??`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) was [introduced in PHP 7.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php).

`$x = $a ?? $b` is equivalent to `$x = isset($a) ? $a : $b`. If `$a` is a complex expression (e.g. a function call), it is evaluated only once.

So no, your two statements are not equivalent.